# Indirect questions usage

Tags: questions, politeness, reported-speech

Sometimes I use the indirect questions as stated below,

> Could you please tell me, where is this address??

Sometimes, I feel it's not correct, although it's understandable to any person. So tell me, is it grammatically correct?

I usually use phrase before the direct questions. Is that the correct way for polite questions?

Answer (score 0):

Asking that way makes you sound like a non-native speaker of the english language.

One "word nit": If you're going to ask that, use "would you", not "could you."  Because if you're going to be formal, "could" ask for capability, "would" asks for capability and willingness to actually do it.

I would rephrase your question as

> "Would you tell me how to get to this address?"